# Partial column names using `$`. Bug or feature?

Tags: r

I noticed after mistyping a column name (omitting the last letter) that data.frame still returns the values of that column. Example:

```
dt <- data.frame(Column = LETTERS[1:10], Col = 1:10)

# Using the first 4 letters of the first column returns:
dt$Colu
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

# Using the first 3 letters of first column/full column name of second 
# column returns:
dt$Col
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

# using the first two letters of both columns (ambiguous) returns:
dt$Co
 NULL
```

I was just wondering if this is expected behavior.

R3.5.0

Comment: search for partial matching in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html. basically the dollar operator `$` in R does partial matching on column names.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, I wasn't aware of that!